# Conversion to swift 3 doesn't compile everything in swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I have converted my project to Swift 3 not long ago.

Everything is in Swift 3, project, pods etc.

Problem is,

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath)`

is still called for my tableview delegate rather than

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

I tried with a new project from scratch, the problem doesn't happen.
I restarted XCode, cleaned build folder, deleted derived data... nothing works :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem is,
>
> ```
> func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath)
> ```
>
> is still called for my tableview delegate rather than
>
> ```
> func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
> ```

You need to *delete* the first one. Otherwise, yes, it can be called. Also, the second one *must* be inside curly braces for a class declaration that declares adoption of UITableViewDelegate (or inherits from UITableViewController).

Comment: Problem is, it's like you suggest to do it, I don't have both functions together, but if I use didSelectRowAt alone, it's never called

Comment: I assure you that it will be, if you do all of what I said.

Comment: so I found what doesn't work, **if** the superclass of my `UIViewController` which conform to the table delegate doesn't implement the said functions **then** my view controller doesn`t have the swift3 version of methods called.
I guess this isn't a normal behavior.

Comment: Which is exactly what I said in my answer.  I said you must be inside curly braces where adoption of the delegate is explicitly declared. Not inherited. Explicit.

Comment: But why is that ? Plus I can't redeclare the protocol adoption in the subclass

Comment: It's because of Swift 3 stupid renamification of Objective C method names. It affects especially optional protocol methods in the way I described. The adoption and implementation must occur explicitly together. Otherwise Cocoa can't find the method. You might be able to work around this with an `@objc` declaration of the true Objective C name, but I don't promise anything.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you very much for sharing your knowledge :)

Answer (score -1):

Change `didSelectecRowAt` to `cellForRowAt`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    ...
```

and add in:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    ...
```

Comment: I mean it's nice to try, but this answer just make no sense regarding my question